# Actor ‘self’ can only be passed ‘inout’ from an async initializer

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-concurrency

In Swift, let’s say we have an actor, which has a private struct.
We want this actor to be reactive, and to give access to a publisher that publishes a specific field of the private struct.

The following code seems to work. But it produces a warning I do not understand.

```swift
public actor MyActor {
    
    private struct MyStruct {
        var publicField: String
    }
    
    @Published
    private var myStruct: MyStruct?
    
    /* We force a non isolated so the property is still accessible from other contexts w/o await in other modules. */
    public nonisolated let publicFieldPublisher: AnyPublisher<String?, Never>
    
    init() {
        self.publicFieldPublisher = _myStruct.projectedValue.map{ $0?.publicField }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
}
```

The warning:

```
Actor 'self' can only be passed 'inout' from an async initializer
```

What does that mean? Is it possible to get rid of this warning? Is it “dangerous” (can this cause issues later)?

*Note*:
If I use `$myStruct` instead of `_myStruct.projectedValue`, it does not compile at all. I think it’s related, but I don’t truly see how.

The error is in that case:

```
'self' used in property access '$myStruct' before all stored properties are initialized
```

Comment: You are supposed to make one question at a time

Comment: I have rephrased.

Comment: What if you say `init() { [self] in` ?

Comment: @matt w/ this we get an error: use of variable before initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because when you are using `_myStruct.projectedValue` compiler notes that you are trying to do mutation on the actor from a synchronous context. All you have to do to remove the warning is to make your initializer asynchronous using `async` specifier.

The [actor initializer proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0327-actor-initializers.md) goes into more detail for why initializer needs to be asynchronous if there mutations inside actor initializer. Cosider the following case:

```swift
actor Clicker {
  var count: Int
  func click() { self.count += 1 }

  init(bad: Void) {
    self.count = 0
    // no actor hop happens, because non-async init.

    Task { await self.click() }

    self.click() //  this mutation races with the task!

    print(self.count) //  Can print 1 or 2!
  }
}
```

Since there are two `click` method call one from Task and one called directly, there might be a case that the Task call executed first and hence the next call need to wait until that finishes.